# How to set custom DriverConnectionProvider with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How to set custom DriverConnectionProvider with Fluent NHibernate?

Best regards,
Alexey Zakharov

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I find solution. Here is the small sample, which how it could be done.

```
Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                    .ConnectionString(".......")
                    .ShowSql()
                    .Provider<TenantConnectionProvider>()
                    )

public class TenantConnectionProvider : DriverConnectionProvider
{
    public override IDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        IDbConnection conn = Driver.CreateConnection();
        try
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = // Tenant connection string provider called here
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            conn.Dispose();
            throw;
        }

        return conn;


   }
}
```

Comment: The key point here is that the ConnectionString must be set with something, and it can't be empty string.

Comment: Hi Alexey, Will it work for every Session ??

for ex: i am using SAAS application,  one application for multi tenant and each tenant has its own database. So whenever tenant-user log in , based upon tenant i know which database i want to point it . so the override method 
public overried  IDbConnection  GetConnection() will gets invoke ??

In One Application with One database, i used to configure the Nhibenate inside global.asax file, which is one time initialization when application runs.

Comment: correct me, the method GetConnection() will get invoked whenever nhibernate wants to connect database ??

so if i manage to prepare the dynamic connectionString (conn.ConnectionString =  dynamicConnectionString), then everything will take care by Nhibenate ??