# NHIbernate SessionFactory and Configuration Recreation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, castle-windsor, sessionfactory

I have one difficult situation.

As we know NH `SessionFactory` is a singleton in our app.

> "Heavyweight, thread-safe, and you only should ever have one per
>   database".

And `SessionFactory` is created from `Configuration().BuildSessionFactory()` where `Configuration()` is my fluently configured database.

**Here is the poblem.** 
I need to use different users for my connection string in an MVC app. This is needed to connect to the database by different users. When connection is ok, then I use NH to manipulate domain mapped objects.

**Question here is** *how to pass different users to `Configuration`* and use this `SessionFactory` in case when we need create `Configuration` first of all? Creating the `SessionFactory` again is a wrong way, right?

And this *becomes more harder* because **I use Windsor container to register all objects** before my MVC app's run.

Comment: What is the RDBMS? I know SQL Server supports `Integrated Security = SSPI` that will pass the user specific credentials along.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are wanting to provide a different connection string for different users of your application.

NHibernate has a feature in which you can provide your own DriverConnectionProvider which will allow you to ultimately be able to create custom connection strings on the fly by overriding the GetConnection() method.

Example:

```
class DynamicConnectionProvider : DriverConnectionProvider
{
    public override IDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        IDbConnection connection = Driver.CreateConnection();

        try
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = // Add your logic for dynamically creating a connection string

            connection.Open();
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            connection.Dispose();

            throw;
        }

        return connection;
    }
}
```

You can also take a look at the following links for examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2927967/670028
- http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/09/18/extending-nhibernate-s-driverconnectionprovider.aspx

And yes, creating duplicate SessionFactories would be quite costly to your applications memory usage, would complicate your applications architecture, and is really unnecessary as there are other options such as the one I listed above.

Comment: +1 briliant (I was almost sure that it would be much much more difficult)

Comment: yeah, I found this solution on the nhforge too. Thank you. One moment is that I override `ConnectionString` property in my implementation. Does there any cons for this?

Comment: No, there are no cons. I've helped manage a very large web application that does this same type of thing and we have not encountered any issues.